# ROS Publish Stereo Image From 2 USB Cameras

Tags: ros, cameras, stereo-vision, monocular

I have two monocular USB cameras and I want to use ROS to make it a stereo camera. I am having a hard time finding a ROS package that consumes 2 monocular camera image streams and publishes a depth map or point cloud. These are the ROS topics available for the 2 ROS cameras:

```
/my_stereo/left/camera_info
/my_stereo/left/image_raw
/my_stereo/right/camera_info
/my_stereo/right/image_raw
/my_stereo_both/parameter_descriptions
/my_stereo_both/parameter_updates
/my_stereo_l/parameter_descriptions
/my_stereo_l/parameter_updates
/my_stereo_r/parameter_descriptions
```

How can I do this? Any help is truly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a simple node which subscribes to the 2 RGB feeds, uses blob matching (look up [Stereo matching in OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/dba/classcv_1_1StereoBM.html) or [Stereo Binary SGBM](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/d9f/classcv_1_1stereo_1_1StereoBinarySGBM.html)) to create the stereo image, and publishes it.

Alternately, I think OpenCV contains the functionality for image_to_pointcloud conversion.